# Redirecting web content but not the name of web page address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have two internet addressess, say one.com and two.com
The content of my webpage is all under the domain one.com. If I hit address two.com I want it to redirect to one.com but still with address two.com. For example if I type in address bar two.com/article. I want to still show this same address but the content displayed would be as from address one.com/article

I tried to use htaccess file, but still no luck.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve that while performing an external redirect.

If both domains are hosted on the same server, then you can perform an internal redirect (e.g. using Apache's Alias, AliasMatch or mod_rewrite).

If the domains are hosted on different servers, then you would have to proxy one of them. You could do this with ProxyPass from Apache's mod_proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your domain name provider and create an alias (CNAME record) for the address.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enable **`mod_proxy`** in your Apache config for that. Once mod_proxy is enabled, enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory on `domain2.com` host:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain1.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P,NC]
```